# Multiple layers of absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I am creating a comment stream layout, that has a bar in the background that has position:absolute. The comment items are placed on top of the bar. This works fine, but I also would like people to be able to mention other users in the comment. 
The dropdown menu that will open when typing @ however is placed behind the consecutive comment. The dropdown menu is also using position: absolute whereas the comment has position:relative. Now it seems that these multiple layers don't work well together.

```
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="comment">
    <input placeholder="mention someone with @username">
    <div class="mention-dropdown">
      <div class="mention">username</div>
      <div class="mention">username</div>
      <div class="mention">username</div>
      <div class="mention">username</div>
      <div class="mention">username</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    some comment text
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    some comment text
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    some comment text
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    some comment text
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    some comment text
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    some comment text
  </div>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="start">
    start
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.timeline {
  .comment {
    input {
      width: 100%;
    }
    z-index: 10;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(102, 255, 255);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    .mention-dropdown {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: gray;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 20;
    }
  }
  .background {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    .bar {
      top: 0;
      width: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      border: blue solid 2px;
      position: absolute;
      left: calc(50% - 3px);
    }
  }
  .start {
    left: calc(50% - 3px);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

I recreated the problem in a code pen:
https://codepen.io/timolemow/pen/eEKVLN

Any help greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell from the code pen, but is there any reason to keep absolute positioning on .mention-dropdown?  Removing it shows the entire dropdown.

Comment: Yes, otherwise the dropdown will increase the size of the comment, which looks weird. As it's a dropdown, it should not affect the underlying content, but hover over it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove position relative on all div.comment and add only on the first.

```
.timeline .comment-wrapper {
  position:relative; 
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzKvpq

Comment: The problem still persists, the bar is now in front of the comment - but it should be behind everything else. First the bar, on top of that the comments, on top of that the dropdown.

Comment: I tried adding z-index: -1; to .background on the above codepen, and it seemed to work.  If that works and gets added to the above answer, it may be complete, hopefully.